# Implementing Authorization code flow entering username and password

Tags: .net-core, identityserver4

I'm new at Identity Server 4.
I'm deploying a solution with three projects: a console app, a web api and Identity Server 4.
I want to get an access token entering username and password in my console app. 
I ask if it's possible to do that with no using Resource Owner Password flow, but using just Hybrid Flow? How can I do it in my console application?

**Update question**

I'm deploying  a console app to simulate a native application that is the end goal. After reading several documents I decide to use Authorization code flow that is what I need in my case.

The problem is that the user (in this case my console app) has to enter username and password to authenticate. But with Authorization code I authenticate the client, not the user. Right?

I'm saying this because I cannot send username and password to the authorize endpoint to get authorization code.

Do I have before authenticate the client with the Authorization code flow and then authenticate the user with Resource Owner Password flow?
What are the steps?

Comment: Is it a requirement that the SPA application has its own login screen or are you ok with the typical approach where the login screen is on the IdentityServer? You normally want to do it this way to prevent something on the device from getting the username and password.

Comment: @aaronR The ideal is to use App's login screen and not the Identity Server's login screen. I found a lot of example with the typical approach where the login screen is on the Identity Server. But I need to use App's login screen.

Comment: If this is something that will be installed like a mobile application, are you aware of the security risks with that approach?

Comment: Is there an example of this? An authentication with a mobile application that uses its own login page using authorization code flow?
What are the risks of this approach? @aaronR

Comment: First I’m not sure you can mix those two. Second the security risks are that another app or malicious code on the mobile device could listen in and steal the username and passwords. Where if you use the IdentityServer4 or any other server that is protected with a SSL certificate it is a lot harder to steal the username and password.

Comment: So I understood I have to use Identity Server's login page, right?
I thought I could create a customize login page for my app and not use the Identity Server's login page @aaronR

Comment: You can customize the login page in IdentityServer4. If you are ok with the users logging in on the mobile device and that is a low risk to you for the app then just use the Resource Owner Password flow.

Comment: I have to use the Authorization code flow, not the Resource Owner Password flow. Thanks for the answers @aaronR. Do you confirm me I can customize login page in Identity Server4? Could you find me an example of this?

Comment: Here is the direct link for the sample login page from the QuickStart example project for IdentityServer4. https://github.com/IdentityServer/IdentityServer4.Quickstart.UI/blob/release/Views/Account/Login.cshtml

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/157721/discussion-between-fabio97-and-aaronr).

Answer (score 0):

Let me define some of the Grant Types and other terms that IdentityServer4 supports to help answer the questions.

This is taken from the [IdentityServer documents](http://docs.identityserver.io/en/release/topics/grant_types.html) and Scott Brady's [blog](https://www.scottbrady91.com/OpenID-Connect/OpenID-Connect-Flows).

**Access Token** ([reference](https://alexbilbie.com/guide-to-oauth-2-grants/))

An access token represents a permission granted to a client to access some protected resources.

**Resource Owner Password Flow**

The client directly receives the username and password, typically from the user, and passes them to the Authorization Server (IdentityServer4) and receives an Access Token.

The client would not have a response_type and the client on the Authorization Server would be defined as:

```
new Client
{
    ClientId = "ResourceOwnerCodeFlowClient",
    ClientName = "Resource Owner Code Flow Client",
    AllowedGrantTypes = GrantTypes.ResourceOwnerPassword

    //....Other properties to complete the client
}
```

**Hybrid Flow**

This is a flow that is the same as using Implicit and Authorization Code flows.
These would be defined on the client as response_type `'code id_token'` and on the Authorization Server as:

```
new Client
{
    ClientId = "HybridCodeFlowClient",
    ClientName = "Hybrid Code Flow Client",
    AllowedGrantTypes = GrantTypes.Hybrid

    //....Other properties to complete the client
}
```

**Authorization Code Flow**

This is used to obtain an authorization code that is often exchanged for an identity token or access token. This may also be used to authenticate the client application. These would be defined on the client as response_type `'code'` and on the Authorization Server as:

```
new Client
{
    ClientId = "AuthCodeFlowClient",
    ClientName = "Authorizate Code Flow Client",
    AllowedGrantTypes = GrantTypes.Code

    //....Other properties to complete the client
}
```

**Implicit Flow**

The Authorization server returns an access token directly after the user logs into the server. These would be defined on the client as response_type `'token'` and on the Authorization Server as:

```
new Client
{
    ClientId = "ImplicitCodeFlowClient",
    ClientName = "Implicit Code Flow Client",
    AllowedGrantTypes = GrantTypes.Implicit

    //....Other properties to complete the client
}
```

**Client Credentials Flow**

Typically used for machine-to-machine authentication when a specific user is not required. The Authorization server responds with an access token. These would be defined on the client as response_type `'token'` and on the Authorization Server as:

```
new Client
{
    ClientId = "ClientCredentialsCodeFlowClient",
    ClientName = "Client Credentials Code Flow Client",
    ClientSecrets = 
                {
                    new Secret("secret".Sha256())
                },
    AllowedGrantTypes = GrantTypes.ClientCredentials

    //....Other properties to complete the client
}
```

***Answer:***

*Non-Interactive User*
If you are using a console application as the final design choice for your solution and there will be no direct user input, where it will run more like a service you should use the `Client Credentials Grant Type`.

*Interactive User*
If you will have users that will be using the console application interactively then keep using the Resource Owner Password flow because the Hybrid Flow, due to the inclusion of the Authorization Code Flow, will force the login to occur on the Authorization Server.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I'm deploying a console app to simulate an native app that it will be the end choice. So the user has to enter username and password in the mobile app and the mobile app has to authenticate via identity server. I ask if Authorization code flow is the best approach in my case?  And why not the hybrid flow?

Comment: If your end goal is to have a native app then please add that to the question and I'll add to my answer.

Answer (score 0):

It is recommended to use the system browser for auth when using implicit or hybrid flows and it's certainly just as possible to do this in a test console app as it is in a full blown desktop app or mobile app. 
Check out this library: https://github.com/IdentityModel/IdentityModel.OidcClient2 and in particular this sample: https://github.com/IdentityModel/IdentityModel.OidcClient2/tree/release/clients/ConsoleClientWithBrowser

Comment: I updated the question beacuse I need to use Authorization code flow after reading different documents. I ask if it's possibile use authorization code flow in a console app (that simulates the native app).